# How to write LINQ query for getting object from another object using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops, object

I have convert following foreach loop into LINQ statement.

```
foreach (Plant plant in Plant.ListPlants)
{
    foreach (Program program in plant.GetAllPrograms())
    {
        if (program.GetProfitCenter() != null)
        {
            foreach (CostCenter costCenter in program.GetProfitCenter().GetAllCostCenters())
            {
                foreach (Account account in costCenter.GetAccounts())
                {
                    if (account.Code == Code)//Code is a parameter
                    {
                        return account;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result should return null also whenever there is no such account code exists. 
Please help me to frame LINQ for the above loops.

Comment: I tried with this " Plant.ListPlants.First(plant => plant.GetAllPrograms().First(program => program.GetProfitCenter() != null && program.GetProfitCenter().GetAllCostCenters().First(costCenter => costCenter.GetAccounts().First(account => account.Code == Code))));" But it is showing Cannot implicitly convert Account into bool

Comment: It's a little hard to read but I think you need to add ( ) around costCenter => costCenter.GetAccounts().First(account => account.Code == Code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (from plant in Plant.ListPlants
from program in plant.GetAllPrograms()
where program.GetProfitCenter() != null
from costCenter in program.GetProfitCenter().GetAllCostCenters()
from account in costCenter.GetAccounts()
where account.Code == Code
select account).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should work, I used ReSharper feature to convert foreach to LINQ and unlike toadflakz solution it should not throw an exception when `program.GetProfitCenter() == null`.

Comment: I choosed this answer because there is I think performance wise both are same but no need of any local variables to store intermediate result as like in Tim Schmelter's answer.

Comment: @sanmathi: `accounts` does not store anything but the query, only `FirstOrDefault` will execute it. So using a variable increases readability and maintainability(for example if you want to return all sometime) and costs nothing. It also makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @sanmathi: there is no difference in performance due to LINQ's deferred execution. The query itself is (nearly) a No-Op.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter is correct, his answer should be accepted probably as he posted sooner. My just saves one line of code, no real difference here.

Comment: You could inline the variable from Tim's answer (i.e., `return Plants.ListPlants....Where(acc => acc.Code == Code).FirstOrDefault();`).  The real difference between the two answers is that Michal uses query syntax rather than method syntax (AKA fluent syntax AKA lambda syntax) ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)).  Different people have different preferences between the two syntaxes, though some queries are much cleaner in one or the other.  Query syntax compiles to method syntax, so there is no performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 6):

Use `SelectMany`

```
var accounts = Plant.ListPlants
    .SelectMany(lp => lp.GetAllPrograms())
    .Where(p => p.GetProfitCenter() != null)
    .SelectMany(p => p.GetProfitCenter().GetAllCostCenters())
    .SelectMany(cc => cc.GetAccounts())
    .Where(acc => acc.Code == Code);
return accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not unlike the code you've already written, except you do all the filtering at the end.

```
var accounts = 
    from plant in Plant.ListPlants
    from program in plant.GetAllPrograms()
    from costCenter in program.GetProfitCenter().GetAllCostCenters()
    from account in costcenter.GetAccounts()
    where program.GetProfitCenter() != null && 
          account.Code == Code
    select account;
return accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

I can't guarantee this will work but it should give you a good idea on where to start.